# Why does my hostname contain odd characters?

Tags: hostname

I installed Ubuntu, went straight to the Terminal and noticed there is some odd characters in my name. Here's what it is:

```
imageek@imageek-DP700A3D-DM700A3D-DB701A3D-DP700A7D:
```

How do I change this?

Comment: To answer the *Why?* part: Those are not odd characters, that is the *Product name* of your computer. If you choose the default values at installation your hostname will be set to *username-productname*. Your BIOS identifies your machine as DP700A3D-DM700A3D-DB701A3D-DP700A7D (or "DP700A3D DM700A3D DB701A3D DP700A7D"). So we now know that you have a Samsung All-in-one PC.

Answer (score 9):

You can "test" a new hostname with the command :

```
sudo hostname new_hostname
```

(this will not last after reboot)

---

**SOLUTION 1 :** Edit `/etc/hostname`, and replace the current name *imageek-DP700A3D-DM700A3D-DB701A3D-DP700A7D* with the new one.

```
gksu gedit /etc/hostname
```

---

**SOLUTION 2 :** You can also use :

```
sysctl kernel.hostname
```

to read the current hostname, and

```
sudo sysctl kernel.hostname=NEW_HOSTNAME
```

to change it.

**/!\ ATTENTION** : When using any of those methods, you will also want to change your hostname in `/etc/hosts` to avoid the error message when using `sudo` : "*sudo* : *unable to resolve hostname* new_hostname" :

```
gksu gedit /etc/hosts
```

---

**SOLUTION 3 :** You can also do this with a graphical interface. You have to install `gnome-network-admin` :

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-network-admin
```

Comment: There is no need to edit /etc/hosts , its for ip mapping

Comment: Well, in `/etc/hosts`, you have a line 127.0.1.1 *hostname*. And on the french Ubuntu-fr.org, I can see they recommend to edit both files.

Comment: no its not necessary for his case , the name is the host-name for his machine , try just to edit the host-name and it will change ,

Comment: /etc/hosts act like dns you can map a name to an ip so if you type localhost the computer know that its ip is 127.0.0.1

Comment: I just changed `/etc/hostname` and rebooted, without changing the `/etc/hosts` file, you have an error : `sudo : unable to resolve host new_hostname`. I'm guessing you're wrong here.

Comment: you should mention the use of /etc/hosts for this purpose not for changing the name in terminal .

Comment: that a good answer my friend , i hope we just learn from conversation don't take it as personal view

Comment: I just edited with your recommendation. I think it's more readable now. I've added the /etc/hosts thing in a note.